# onActivityResult in android

Tags: android, file, android-intent

in my application i'm retrieving image from sdcard and sending path of image back to previous activity.i'm not able to open image using that path.how can i do this.

code -

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==1)
    {
        Uri path=data.getData();
        File f;
        System.out.println(";;;;;;;;;;;;"+path);//geting null


    }
}
```

in 2nd activity-

```
 for(j=1;j<idcount;j++){
            if(ch[j].isChecked())
            {

                System.out.println("PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP"+j);
                i=new Intent();
                i.putExtra("files",image[++j]);// image is array of file
                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
            }       
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the getDataString() method?

Also I am not sure if this is completely what you want, but you could try doing something like:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
Uri uri = (Uri)bundle.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

Comment: not working.giving nullpointer exception at Uri uri = (Uri)bundle.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);